# How to query All Types of document from Alfresco repository using CMIS

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, cmis, alfresco-webscripts

I have Multiple Custom content types, and based on individual type i am able to query documents. But my requirement is i want to get all types of document.

I wrote query select * from hr:hrdoctype, Because my hr:hrdoctype is my parent type for all other types. But its not working.

But if i will write select * from hr:hrReimbursment, This is working fine.

So how can i get all All Custom types of documents with single parent type or with single condition.
Please see the Below configuration.

in this case if i will use specific content type then its working fine. but i want to get all type of document using single query.

Please help me how can i write CMIS Query for this requirement.

Share-config-custom.xml:-

```
                <type name="cm:content">
                   <subtype name="hr:hrdoctype" />
                </type>

                <type name="hr:hrdoctype">
                   <subtype name="hr:hrReimbursment" />
                   <subtype name="hr:hrMISCELLANEOUS" />
                   <subtype name="hr:hrWELFARE_POLICIES" />
                   <subtype name="hr:hrGENERAL_POLICIES" />
                   <subtype name="hr:hrPOLICIES_SIGNOFF_NOTES_FILE_NOTES" />
                   <subtype name="hr:hrPHOTOGRAPH" />
                   <subtype name="hr:hrPIF_PROFILE_OVERVIEW" />
                   <subtype name="hr:hrMPR_FORM" />
                   <subtype name="hr:hrPSYOMETRIC_REPORT" />
                   <subtype name="hr:hrTECHNICAL_TEST_ASSESSEMENT" />
                   <subtype name="hr:hrINTERVIEW_ASSESSEMENT_SHEET" />                                     

            </type>
```

Custom-content-model.xml:-

```
     <types>
         <type name="hr:hrdoctype">
            <title>HR Document</title>
            <parent>cm:content</parent>

            <properties>
                <property name="hr:employeeNumber">
                        <title>Employee Number</title>
                        <type>d:text</type>
                        </property>
                <property name="hr:employeeName">
                        <title>Employee Name</title>
                        <type>d:text</type>
                </property>                             
            </properties>

        </type>

        <type name="hr:hrReimbursment">
            <title>REIMBURSEMENT</title>
            <parent>hr:hrdoctype</parent>


            <properties>
                <property name="hr:DocumentDescription">
                        <title>Document Description</title>
                        <type>d:text</type>                         
                </property> 

                <property name="hr:ReimbursmentDate">
                        <title>Reimbursment Date</title>
                        <type>d:text</type>                         
                </property> 

            </properties>

        </type>

        <type name="hr:hrMISCELLANEOUS">
            <title>MISCELLANEOUS</title>
            <parent>hr:hrdoctype</parent>   

            <properties>
                <property name="hr:DocumentDescription1">
                        <title>Document Description</title>
                        <type>d:text</type>                         
                </property> 

            </properties>

        </type>
</types>
```

Comment: It looks like you've pasted in a snippet of Share configuration. What we need to see is your content model XML to show that each of those types really is a sub-type of hr:hrdoctype.

Comment: @Jeff Potts    I have Edited my question, and added sample snipet of my custom content model. Please check it once.   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested simillar case on my repository.

There are four base CMIS types: `cmis:document`, `cmis:folder`, `cmis:relationship`, `cmis:policy`. Types **`cmis:document`** and **`cmis:folder`** must be supported by any repository.

I my case the `myc:xyz` type inherits from the `cmis:folder` type.

1. CMIS query selecting all folders:

   ```
   select * from cmis:folder where cmis:name='ABCD'
   ```

   returns folder:

   ```
   {
       "cmis:objectId": "5b97929c-553b-4494-91cc-2c18e50b2f1c",
       "cmis:objectTypeId": "F:myc:xyz",
       "cmis:baseTypeId": "cmis:folder",
       "cmis:name": "ABCD"
   }
   ```
2. CMIS query selecting all `myc:xyz` folders:

   ```
   select * from myc:xyz where cmis:name='ABCD'
   ```

   return the same folder with some `myc:xyz` type's additional properties:

   ```
   {
       "cmis:objectId": "5b97929c-553b-4494-91cc-2c18e50b2f1c",
       "cmis:objectTypeId": "F:myc:xyz",
       "cmis:baseTypeId": "cmis:folder",
       "cmis:name": "ABCD",

       "myc:AdditionalProperty1": "1111",
       "myc:AdditionalProperty2": "2222"
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.

[OpenCMIS Client API Developer's Guide](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/guide.html)

PS. You can test queries with Alfresco CMIS 1.1 ["The Browser binding"](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/pra/1/concepts/cmis-1.1-browser-binding.html).
For example, this is URL for the query `select * from cmis:folder where cmis:name='ABCD'` (Firefox automatically decoding encoded parameters in URL, it is very comfortable):

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser/?cmisselector=query&succinct=true&q=select * from cmis:folder where cmis:name='ABCD'
```

Comment: I wrote the query, select * from cmis:document, But Its giving Some Unnecessary fileslike ftl, xml and js. Here my requirement is, I have 72 custom types of documents. and I want node reference of only those 72 types using Single parent type.

Comment: Try this one, it should be working: select cmis:name, cmis:objectTypeId, cmis:baseTypeId from hr:hrdoctype

Comment: In my Application, After query it returns only first 100 records from repository.  So how can i get more than 100 records??

Comment: use parameters: &maxItems=10&skipCount=20

Comment: Where do i use this parameter?

Comment: in http request... how do you select nodes? Please ask a separate stackoverflow question and include source code.